# tcp socket : what is the way to make all clients connected at different times receive the same data using c language?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

About TCP socket, when a client connects to the server, the server sends datas to the specified server port, and the client reads datas from this port. Can the later connected clients only read new datas? If so, what is the way to make all clients connected at different times receive the same datas?

For example:

The client 1 connects to the server, the server sends the data "123456",
2 seconds later, the client 2 alse connects to the server, now the server will send data "abcdefg". if I want the client 2 also received the data "123456", I have to resend data "123456", a question occured:the client 1 received the data "123456" again, because the two client use same server port.I want to send a time, but the 2 client can received.

Comment: The server would need to handle that. For example by replicating the data to very connected socket.

Comment: You have to write this logic into the server. It shall be the server to manage what to send to the client(s) on the basis how what each client is asking or expecting.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I have added an example.

Comment: @kaylum  What is "very connected socket"?

Comment: sorry, "every" not "very"

Comment: @Sir Jo Black  OK, I thought there was a system API to set this logic.

Comment: Why would client 1 receive the data again? You have to send any data to each connected client separately. It's up to you to sort out who got what and send new (or old) data accordingly

Comment: @ Gerhardh Becasue all connected clients read same server port. the client 1 is always connected the server,  after the client 2 connected, the client 1 also can receive the data again.

Comment: That can only happen if you send the data again to that client. While they connect to the same port, they still have independent TCP connections. You don't send to "all connected clients" but you send to each connections separately.

Comment: "Server sends data to the specified server port": no it doesn't. It sends data via the accepted socket. There is one of those per client, and often a thread per client, so in theory they can all achieve simultaneity, but it is most unlikely in practice. Your question is founded on a false assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*a question occured:the client 1 received the data "123456" again, because the two client use same server port.*"

No, that will not happen. The server-client connection consists of the server ip+port and the client ip+port, where the client port will be unique during the session (it will not be the port it connected to). Any message the server sends trough this connected socket will be sent with the destination of the client ip+port and will only reach one receiver.